# How to decorate objects in a single line of code using the decorator pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator

I am learning the *decorator pattern* from the [Head First Design Patterns book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) , and here's what I've coded (C++) to get the pattern to work:

```
#include <iostream>


class AbstractType
{
public: 
    virtual double value() const = 0;
};


class FirstConcreteType
    :
    public AbstractType
{
public: 
    double value() const 
    {
        return 1; 
    }
};

class SecondConcreteType
    : 
    public AbstractType
{
public:
    double value() const
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

class DecoratorType
    :
    public AbstractType
{
    const AbstractType* decoratedObject_; 

public:

    DecoratorType(const AbstractType& abstractObject)
        :
    decoratedObject_(&abstractObject)
    {}

    DecoratorType(const DecoratorType& decoratorObject)
        :
    decoratedObject_(&decoratorObject)
    {}

    virtual double value() const = 0; 

    const AbstractType& getObject() const
    {
        return *decoratedObject_; 
    }
};

class FirstDecoratorType
    :
    public DecoratorType
{
public:
    FirstDecoratorType(const AbstractType& abstractObject)
        :
    DecoratorType(abstractObject)
    {}

    FirstDecoratorType(const DecoratorType& decoratorObject)
        :
    DecoratorType(decoratorObject)
    {}

    double value() const
    {
        const AbstractType& object = getObject(); 

        return 1 + object.value(); 
    }
};

class SecondDecoratorType
    :
    public DecoratorType
{
public:
    SecondDecoratorType(const AbstractType& abstractObject)
        :
    DecoratorType(abstractObject)
    {}

    SecondDecoratorType(const DecoratorType& decoratorObject)
        :
    DecoratorType(decoratorObject)
    {}

    double value() const
    {
        const AbstractType& object = getObject(); 

        return 2 + object.value(); 
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // When I decorate sequentially, it works fine

    SecondConcreteType secondConc;

    FirstDecoratorType firstDec(secondConc); 
    cout << firstDec.value() << endl;

    SecondDecoratorType secondDec(firstDec); 
    cout << secondDec.value() << endl;

    FirstDecoratorType firstDecSecond (secondDec); 
    cout << firstDecSecond.value() << endl; 

    // Decorating in a single line, messes things up, since there is no
    // constructor taking the value argument defined.  
    //FirstDecoratorType firstDynamicDec (SecondConcreteType()); 
    //cout << firstDynamicDec.value() << endl;

    return 0;
};
```

In the main program, the object of theh ConcreteType must be created first, and then it is decorated using composition of the pointer to the AbstractType (within the DecoratorType). It works fine, if I create the concrete objects, and create the new decorated objects one after another..

What do I need to do in order for the DecoratorType to be able to decorate objects using composition in a single line of code (commented out line in the example code)? Would something like this be useful at all in the "real world"? I (obviously) don't have a lot of experience in using design patterns.. so it's difficult for me to see what functionality I should aim at.

EDIT:

Here's a version working with basic pointers (valgrind shows no memory leaks, and states that no memory leaks are possible):

```
#include <iostream>


class AbstractType
{
    public: 
        virtual double value() const = 0;

        virtual ~AbstractType() {}; 
};

class FirstConcreteType
:
    public AbstractType
{
    public: 
        double value() const 
        {
            return 1; 
        }
};

class SecondConcreteType
: 
    public AbstractType
{
    public:
        double value() const
        {
            return 2;
        }
};

class DecoratorType
:
    public AbstractType
{
    const AbstractType* decoratedObject_; 
    bool own_;

    public:

        DecoratorType(const AbstractType& abstractObject)
            :
                decoratedObject_(&abstractObject), 
                own_(false)
        {}

        DecoratorType(const DecoratorType& decoratorObject)
            :
                decoratedObject_(&decoratorObject), 
                own_(false)

        {}

        DecoratorType (AbstractType* abstractPtr)
            : 
                decoratedObject_(abstractPtr), 
                own_(true)
        {}

        DecoratorType (DecoratorType* decoratorPtr)
            :
                decoratedObject_(decoratorPtr), 
                own_(true)
        {}

        virtual ~DecoratorType()
        {
            if (own_)
            {
                delete decoratedObject_; 
                decoratedObject_ = 0;
            }
        }

        virtual double value() const = 0; 

        const AbstractType& getObject() const
        {
            return *decoratedObject_; 
        }
};

class FirstDecoratorType
:
    public DecoratorType
{
    public:
        FirstDecoratorType(const AbstractType& abstractObject)
            :
                DecoratorType(abstractObject)
        {}

        FirstDecoratorType(const DecoratorType& decoratorObject)
            :
                DecoratorType(decoratorObject)
        {}

        FirstDecoratorType (AbstractType* abstractPtr)
            :
                DecoratorType(abstractPtr)
        {}

        FirstDecoratorType (FirstDecoratorType* decoratorPtr)
            :
                DecoratorType(decoratorPtr)
        {}


        double value() const
        {
            const AbstractType& object = getObject(); 

            return 1 + object.value(); 
        }
};

class SecondDecoratorType
:
    public DecoratorType
{
    public:
        SecondDecoratorType(const AbstractType& abstractObject)
            :
                DecoratorType(abstractObject)
        {}

        SecondDecoratorType(const DecoratorType& decoratorObject)
            :
                DecoratorType(decoratorObject)
        {}

        SecondDecoratorType (AbstractType* abstractPtr)
            :
                DecoratorType(abstractPtr)
        {}

        SecondDecoratorType (SecondDecoratorType* decoratorPtr)
            :
                DecoratorType(decoratorPtr)
        {}

        double value() const
        {
            const AbstractType& object = getObject(); 

            return 2 + object.value(); 
        }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // When I decorate sequentially, it works fine

    SecondConcreteType secondConc;

    FirstDecoratorType firstDec(secondConc); 
    cout << firstDec.value() << endl;

    SecondDecoratorType secondDec(firstDec); 
    cout << secondDec.value() << endl;

    FirstDecoratorType firstDecSecond (secondDec); 
    cout << firstDecSecond.value() << endl; 

    // Decorating in a single line, messes things up, since there is no
    // constructor taking the value argument defined.  
    FirstDecoratorType firstDynamicDec (new SecondDecoratorType (
           new FirstDecoratorType (new SecondConcreteType()))); 

    cout << firstDynamicDec.value() << endl;

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: The problem is that you're saving pointers to object passed in as a `const` reference - which means those may be temporary. Which is bad. You should probably pass in a `shared_ptr` or a `unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I think 'FirstDecoratorType firstDynamicDec (new SecondConcreteType());' is the way to go

Comment: Passing smart pointers will transfer ownership to the decorator. This seems not like what I need, and what the pattern is explaining: to add stuff to objects at runtime. I don't want the destructor of the DecoratorType to delete the decorated object (*ConcreteType).

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see how that can work and still allow the one line thing

Comment: @tomislav-maric If you pass a shared_ptr, then the destructor of your decorator won't destroy your object if there are other shared_ptrs to it- and you obviously shouldn't use raw pointers with owning semantics of an object that has a shared_ptr referencing it. But you clearly have owner semantics here in your Decorator, after all your decorator won't be valid anymore if the decorated object dies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FirstDecoratorType firstDynamicDec (SecondConcreteType());
```

The problem with this is that it does NOT define an object. Instead, it *declares* a function. Look for *most-vexing-parse* in C++ on this site, you will get lots of topics on it.

Short explanation :  the function name is `firstDynamicDec` whose return type is `FirstDecoratorType` and it takes parameter which is again a function returning `SecondConcreteType` and taking no argument.

Comment: That is _a_ problem, but I wouldn't say _the_ problem in this example.

Comment: This is far from the only problem.  The above code also has serious object lifetime issues.

Comment: @Cubic: That is *the* problem with *that* line.

Comment: @Yakk: It depends on the usage. The code which works (the uncommented part) is fine because none of the object goes out of the scope. It doesn't have object lifetime issues.

Comment: @Nawaz Would you agree that if I add a constructor to the DecoratorType that takes a pointer to the AbstractType as an argument is the way to go? In this case, I would add a virtual destructor to the DecoratorType and a boolean variable informing the destructor to delete the AbstractType* only in the case when the construction is done via a pointer?

Comment: @tomislav-maric: Yes. If the constructor takes *pointer* instead of *reference* that would be better, because in that case the class itself indicates to the world that I'm going to use the pointer internally, so *"make sure that the object you pass as pointer exists as long as you use me"*. Or even better if you use *smart pointer*.

Comment: @tomislav-maric No, use a smart pointer. In both the interface and stored internally.  `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are both reasonable candidates.

Comment: @Nawaz &Yakk, if I use the smart pointer as an argument to the constructor, I will still need to have the standard basic pointer as a private attribute of the DecoratorType, since in any other case, the DecoratorType will take over the ownership of the references passed to it. The only thing I get by using the smart pointer as an argument to the DecoratorType constructor is to make sure that in the main() scope, there will be no memory leaks for those pointers that are passed as constructor arguments (they will be dealt with by the pass by value to the constructor).

Comment: @tomislav-maric: Yes, smart pointers has *almost* nothing to do with better design. It is just that if you don't want to take the burden of deleting the object (possibly because *you think* you're not smart enough to handle that properly), then smart pointers assist you there. However, the really smart programmers may avoid using smart pointers, because smart pointers cause the objects to live longer than they need to (the same problem GC has).

Comment: @Nawaz, not if you're careful

Comment: Thinking that you are too smart for smart pointers is a sign you should use smart pointers.  In this case, unique_ptr would be a drop in replacement for the bDeleteLater bool, and probably better.  As an example it would disable your copy ctor.  It documents at ctor site.  It could even fix exception bugs.

Comment: @Nawaz using smart pointers has nothing to do with being too dumb for handling ownership semantics - it's just a way to handle ownership semantics. If your objects live longer than they need to, then you've misused the smart pointer.

Comment: @Cubic: *"If your objects live longer than they need to, then you've misused the smart pointer."*. Exactly. Do you disagree on any point I said?

Comment: @Nawaz "However, the really smart programmers may avoid using smart pointers, because smart pointers cause the objects to live longer than they need to (the same problem GC has)" I understood this as you saying that one should avoid the use of smart pointers, or that smart pointers are an indication of laziness, both of which I disagree with. All the better if that's not what you meant to say.

Comment: @Cubic: Of course, I didn't mean that. Though I believe that with smart pointers programmers will often become lazy, due to which they will come up with bad design from *resource-management* point of view (but then this is not I meant in my previous comment either).

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that

```
FirstDecoratorType firstDynamicDec (SecondConcreteType());
```

does not declare an object at all, but a function. This is called the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) of C++.

But even when you work around that, you have the problem that temporary objects (such as created by `SecondConcreteTpe()`) only exist until the end of the expression, so the pointer within `FirstDecoratorType` would be invalid before you can do anything useful with it.
You can resolve this by using smart pointers to hold the decorated type within the decorator (for example, `std::unique_ptr`). This makes the decorator responsible for cleaning up the decorated type.